# Text fields are showing too much on inactive Input connection in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield

hello friends I am trying to solve this problem since a month but I cannot I tried almost and everything and search every where but I cant find any solution so I am here asking for your help I want to build a login screen but my input text giving me lots of warnings and I do not know what did I wrong

````
import 'package:chat_app/screens/LoginScreen/widgets/login_button.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/screens/utilsscreen/forgetPasswordScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class TextFields extends StatefulWidget {
 static GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 @override
 _TextFieldsState createState() => _TextFieldsState();
}

class _TextFieldsState extends State<TextFields> {
 var passwordController = TextEditingController();
 var emailController = TextEditingController();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
     child: Form(
       key: TextFields.formKey,
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
         children: [
           TextFormField(
               validator: (val) {
                 if (!GetUtils.isEmail(val)) {
                   return "please enter a valid email";
                 } else
                   return null;
               },
               controller: emailController,
               keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
               style:
                   TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
               cursorColor: Colors.black,
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                   prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                   labelText: "Email",
                   enabledBorder:
                       Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.disabledBorder,
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)))),
           SizedBox(
             height: 30,
           ),
           TextFormField(
               validator: (val) {
                 if (val.length < 8) {
                   return "please enter correct password";
                 } else
                   return null;
               },
               controller: passwordController,
               obscureText: true,
               autocorrect: false,
               enableSuggestions: false,
               keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
               style:
                   TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
               cursorColor: Colors.black,
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                   prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                   labelText: "Password",
                   enabledBorder:
                       Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.disabledBorder,
                   border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2),
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)))),
           SizedBox(
             height: 20,
           ),
           TextButton(
             child: Text("Forget Password?",
                 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
             onPressed: () {
               Get.to(ForgetPassword());
             },
           ),
           SizedBox(
             height: 15,
           ),
           Center(child: LoginButton(chekValidation))
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 void chekValidation() {
   if (TextFields.formKey.currentState.validate()) {
     submit();
   }
 }

 void submit() {
   Get.find<LoginController>()
       .login(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
 }
}
    ```


here are these error I am getting I hope this will help you to find a solution and I also want to know should take this warning serious or ignore them 
```    W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 8858): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
   ```
````

Comment: please screenshot

Comment: screen shot of what

Comment: I've just done an update try this

Comment: no bro did not  work

Comment: just see code once more I just edited

Comment: it work for you now ?

Comment: no did not work I tried all possible ways

Comment: What do you mean about not work ? Please add the error

Comment: these are not error these are warnings

Comment: the warning are same as shown above